# How to generate "global documentation" with doxygen

Tags: doxygen, specifications, requirements

I have a fair understanding of both how to document code and how to write "generic documentation" using `@mainpage`, `@page`, `@subpage` and related tags.

I would need to include requirements/specification documentation for the code.

My problem is to keep this kind of documentation (conceptually distinct from code documentation) close to code implementing functionality (i.e.: at least in the same file, sometimes even near specific classes/functions/methods) but still be able to collect it in an orderly fashion and present it in the `@mainpage`, outside file/class hierarchy.

What I would ideally need is to be able to place specific `@page`, `@section`, `@subsection` etc. randomly in the various source files and then be able to `@include` them in a specific order into `@mainpage` or some other `@subpage`.

Even better would be to be able to include the *same* snippet in both class/function full doc (not `@brief`, of course) and in the "front matter" linked in `@mainpage`.

Global effect I need to have is to have a "specification document" where I detail what the various parts of the code need to implement and then the "normal class/function/whatever" documentation doxygen id very good at providing.

The catch (i.e.: what I don't know how to do) is I would like to keep "specification" and implementation together in the source, but separate them in documentation, i.e.:

1. General Description: easy, this goes into `@mainpage`
2. Requirements: most likely at top of source file implementing them, how do I link/include in main page?
3. Specification: either right after Requirements at top of file or somewhere near class/function implementing it; also here I don't know how to link/include in "front matter" AKA: `@mainpage`.
4. Normal code documentation: here only thing I don't know is how include in class/function description the same "doc snippet" already used for (2) and (3).

Is this possible?

If so, what's the best practice?

**Note**: I could get the effect using a separate file for each "doc snippet" and then `@include`ing it in the right places, but that would defeat the whole purpose that's keep Requirements/Specification/code together while separating them in different sections in the resulting documentation.

**Update**: following @albert comment I tried the following:

- in a standard Doxygen comment I added markers:

```
/**
 * Initialization function.
 *
 * [AM_init]
 * It needs to do a long series of tests to ensure AM can actually work.
 *
 * It should also allocate all dynamic memory needed to avoid runtime failures.
 *
...
 * It will be responsibility of system-level daemon to take appropriate action.
 * [AM_init]
 *
 *
 * @param ip_addr
 * @param port
 * @return
 */
static uint32_t AM_init(const char* ip_addr, uint16_t port) {
...
```

- in the "front matter" definition I have (among other things):

```
/**
@page __init Initialization
@snippet{doc} CommandHandler.c AM_init
*/
```

- The function documentation is rendered correctly (i.e.: the markers are removed)
- OTOH the initialization page is "somewhat incomplete":

```
Initialization

    It needs to do a long series of tests to ensure AM can actually work.
```

that's it.

Apparently the tag *is* found, but only the first line is actually included.

**Further Update**: Following @albert answer (accepted) I had success, but the following caveats:

- Included snippet (`[AM_init]`) *must* be in a standard comment, not a doxygen one, otherwise snippet ends up included twice.
- Included snippet *must not* have leading `*` (very common in "standard comments".
- Included comments *should* have HTML controls (e.g.: `<br/>` for line termination) because Markdown constructs ("double newline", in the above case) are **not**recognized.

In retrospect I think "Note" in Doxygen `\snippet['{'option'}'] <file-name> ( block_id )` documentation addresses, more or less all the above, but I find it very cryptic and I would never have understood the implications without my nose being rubbed into them.

The last one is very annoying because I use a lot Lists and Tables and while HTML syntax is much more powerful, it is also much more difficult to write and to read in sources.

Finding a way to lift this limitation would be "very nice".

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Can you give a small example of what you want to achieve? Did you look at commands like `\snippet`?

Comment: @albert: I am currently using "Doxygen version 1.9.1", but I have no problems moving to whatever needed, including compiling from bleeding edge. `@snippet` is not what I need; AFAIK it is to include some code piece in documentation, not what I need. "small example" is pretty difficult, but I will update OP to clarify.

Comment: There is also the option `doc` with the `\snippet` command so `\snippet{doc}` or `\snippetdoc. So you I think with the `\snippet{doc}` possibility you could achieve what you want.

Comment: @albert: it doesn't seem to work, somehow. I will update OP to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code and the current doxygen version (1.9.4 (5d15657a55555e6181a7830a5c723af75e7577e2)) but also with the 1.9.1 (ef9b20ac7f8a8621fcfc299f8bd0b80422390f4b) version, I get good result:

**bb.h**

```
/// \file

/**
@page __init Initialization
@snippet{doc} CommandHandler.c AM_init
*/
```

**CommandHandler.c**

```
/// \file

/**
 * Initialization function.
 */

/* [AM_init]
   It needs to do a long series of tests to ensure AM can actually work.<br>

   It should also allocate all dynamic memory needed to avoid runtime failures.<br>

   It will be responsibility of system-level daemon to take appropriate action.<br>
   [AM_init]
 */
/**
 * \snippet{doc} this AM_init
 *
 * @param ip_addr
 * @param port
 * @return
 */
static uint32_t AM_init(const char* ip_addr, uint16_t port){}
```

**Doxyfile**

```
EXTRACT_STATIC = YES
EXAMPLE_PATH = .
QUIET = YES
```

Note: OP rightfully mentioned in **further update** that there are some things to take care of:

- Included snippet ([AM_init]) must be in a standard comment, not a doxygen one, otherwise snippet ends up included twice.
- Included snippet must not have leading * (very common in "standard comments".
- Included comments should have HTML controls (e.g.: 
   for line termination) because Markdown constructs ("double newline", in the above case) are **not** recognized.

Comment: I accepted the answer, but you might want to update it to address my concerns (see "Further Update" in OP). Thanks.

Comment: Indeed the comment has to be in standard comment, for `\snippet{doc}` and without the `*`, this is unfortunate. The fact that the `*` was not possible and that the `<br>` was needed amazed me a bit, the fact that the `*` are not allowed is mentioned  (a bit hidden) in the documentation note: "The included documentation should not have comment signs in it as they will appear in the documentation as
well." The `<br>` problem might be solvable (i.e. by running  markdown on the snippet), but this has to be properly investigated.

Comment: If you happen to find some way to "run markdown on the snippet" please add a comment here so I can be notified (I have no idea how I could get  that feature). I'm not a Doxygen expert (by far!) but I plan to use it a lot on some projects. I am also pushing for a more widespread usage in the company I work for and this kind of "inconsistencies" are a big drag-back. Many thanks again!

Comment: Not that it is helping you, but the problem is not in the markdown handling but (the output generated by the markdown handling looks OK).

Comment: An issue has been created in the doxygen issue tracker: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/9365